# REGEXP_CONTAINS order and Case statement in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using case statement and REGEXP_CONTAINS.Just wanted to see if the following order will give me the correct output.

```
 (CASE 
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)BUS') THEN "BUS"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)BRA') THEN "BR" 
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)DIG') THEN "TR"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)INS') THEN "INS"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)INV') THEN "INV"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)SAV') THEN "SAV"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)TRA') THEN "TR"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)CC')  THEN "CC"    
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)HL')  THEN "HL"
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)BR')  THEN "BR" 
 
  
 END) as pf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct if you want case insensitive search for the keyword, while in general, string functions are more efficient than REGEX functions, consider to:

```sql
REGEXP_CONTAINS(AdSet, '(?i)BUS') THEN "BUS"

=>

STRPOS(UPPER(AdSet), 'BUS') <> 0 THEN "BUS"
```